# sortedArrayUsingSelector with a parameter

Tags: xcode, sorting, parameters, selector

I'd like to use the sortedArrayUsingSelector method with a custom compare selector I made which need a parameter.

Here's my custom comparator declarator (.h file):

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareWith:(Object *)otherObject AndIntParameter:(int)param;
```

Problem is sortedArrayUsingSelector dont seem to allow a kind of "WithObject" method to pass the parameter. I'm looking for something like this:

```
NSArray *sortedArrayList = [anotherList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareWith:AndIntParameter:) withObject:i];
```

I can avoid this by coding in a dirty way but i'd really rather not to...
Many thanks if you can help.